# How to update the Arraylist every second in onNewIntent and in Android 4.3?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth device on Android 4.3.

I want to update the Arraylist every second.

And in my application. The **DeviceControl.java** will transmit the parameter by using intent and startActivity.

The **Main.java** will receive the parameter from **DeviceControl.java** and put in to Arraylist like the dollowing code.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        onNewIntent(getIntent());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);

        for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(address[i].length() != 1) {
                HashMap<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                item.put("name", name[i]);
                item.put("address", address[i]);
                item.put("RSSI", rssi[i]);
                item.put("Battery", battery[i]);
                list.add(item);

                mdeviceAddress = address[i];

            } else if(address[i].length() == 1)
                    break;
        }

        mHandler.postDelayed(addlist, 1000); //update the list

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.device_list_name_address, 
                        new String[] {"name", "address", "RSSI", "Battery"},
                        new int[] {R.id.device_name, R.id.device_address, R.id.device_rssi, R.id.device_battery} );
        devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

But it only update the list once time when the **DeviceControl.java** launch the intent.
I want it always update the list after **DeviceControl.java** launch the intent.

I have try to type the code of Arraylist in Runnable, but it doesn't work.

What should I do to make the Arraylist auto update ??

**EDIT**

I add the code of runnable of the following

```
final Runnable addlist = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
            {
                if(address[i].length() != 1){
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
                    HashMap<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    item.put("name", name[i]);
                    item.put("address", address[i]);
                    item.put("RSSI", "11111:" + rssi[i]);
                    item.put("Battery", "22222:" + battery[i]);
                    list.add(item);


                    Log.v(TAG, "onNewIntent----------------------------");
                    mdeviceAddress = address[i];
                    Log.v(TAG, "address[" + i + "] = " + address[i]);
                    Log.v(TAG, "GATT[" + i + "] = " + gatt[i]);
                    //並連線到此Address
                    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(Main.this, BluetoothLeService.class);
                    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
                    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

                }else if(address[i].length() == 1)
                    break;
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1500);
        }
    };
```

And type the `mHandler.postDelayed(addlist, 1000);` in OnNewIntent after for loop. The list should should be change from

```
item.put("RSSI", rssi[i]);
item.put("Battery", battery[i]);
```

to

```
item.put("RSSI", "11111:" + rssi[i]);
item.put("Battery", "22222:" + battery[i]);
```

But it didn't change anything.

Comment: are you sure that onNewInten is called every second?

Comment: I didn't call onNewIntent every second, I just call it once time. But I want it update every second after it call once time.

Comment: but what changes these arrays: name, battery, rssi, address?

Comment: When it call first time, it will show the name , address ,rssi ,battery. And I mark the for loop in onNewIntent and move to runnable. Put the  But it doesn't show anything , the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make use of `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update your list?

If not then you can write  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in runnable. That will update your list. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Should I put all the code in for loop in to runnable ?? or I only need to put the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in to runnable ??

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() just notifies your adapter about the changes been taken place in the list and the list is updated but you also need to write the code where you make changes in the list inside the thread. Plz tell me what changes are taking place exactly. Can you show the code where you are changing the list.

Answer (score 0):

See the demo http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/listview-in-one-activity-doesnt-refresh-data-sending-another-activity/

I guess notifyDataSetChanged() does not work since the adapter points to the "old list", not the "new list". Don't create a new ArrayList, use the one tied to the adapter. 
Try this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> tmp = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
//set data
list.clear();
list.addAll(tmp);
```

Hope that helps.